# How to deploy react app in Elastic beanstalk in a docker platform using Travis CI?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, docker, travis-ci

**Environment health has transitioned from Ok to Severe. ELB processes are not healthy on all instances. ELB health is failing or not available for all instances.**

I am deploying a react app in AWS using the docker platform. I am getting HEALTH-Severe issues when I deploy my app. I have also added custom TCP inbound rules in the EC2 instance (source-anywhere).
I am using free tier in AWS. The following is my Dockerfile.

```
FROM node:alpine as builder 
WORKDIR '/app'
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install 
COPY . .
RUN npm run build 



FROM nginx
EXPOSE 80
COPY --from=builder /app/build  /usr/share/nginx/html
```

My .travis.yml file:

```
language: generic
sudo: required
services:
  - docker
before_install:
  - docker build -t username/docker-react -f Dockerfile.dev .
script:
  - docker run -e CI=true username/docker-react npm run test
deploy:
  provider: elasticbeanstalk
  region: us-east-2
  app: "docker-react"
  env: "DockerReact-env"
  bucket_name: "my bucket-name"
  bucket_path: "docker-react"
  on:
    branch: master
  access_key_id: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY
  secret_access_key: $AWS_SECRET_KEY
```

When I open my app I am getting **502 Bad Gateway** error.

Comment: Are you actually exposing the port 80? `EXPOSE` does not make it actually exposed.

Comment: I am not sure about it. What is the exact way to expose port 80?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After reading some of the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/single-container-docker-configuration.html) I figured maybe docker-compose.yml is actually picked up first before anything. Deleting my docker-compose.yml (which I was only using locally) solved the issue for me.